# Collapsing CSS grid column not working for a specific column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using a grid to display some canvases in 3 of 4 columns, called `left-`, `right-` and `middle-` columns. The fourth column on the extreme left will hold other HTML elements and is called `select-column`. The grid is to take up the full width and height of the screen.

The three canvas columns are of equal width and the select column is to be of width of 150 px. That is to say I want the three columns to equally share `100vw-150px` OR equally share `100vw`.

A further requirement is that I want to be able to collapse/hide each of the columns via  button controls. To create the columns I have used:

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 150px) repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
```

So when a column is collapsed it takes up zero space. However what I have found is that when I collapse `select-column` it still continues to take up space. This is not the case for the canvas columns, they work as expected.

A full example is here: [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jpyree?file=src/app/app.component.css) **Updated as below**

You will see that the buttons move as expected but the `select-column` (the white one) always remains and this is not desired.

**Update**

I've updated the stackblitz example with the suggested changes and these are the relevant files:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="select-column" [class.hide-column]="isSelectColumnHidden">
  </div>
  <div class="left-column" [class.hide-column]="isLeftColumnHidden">
    <canvas #leftCanvas class="left-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="middle-column" [class.hide-column]="isMiddleColumnHidden">
    <canvas #middleCanvas class="middle-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column" [class.hide-column]="isRightColumnHidden">
    <canvas #rightCanvas class="right-column"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="controls-container" [class.controls-container-left]="!isSelectColumnHidden">
  <button class="control-button" (click)="toggleColumn('select')" >{{isSelectColumnHidden ? 'Show Select' : 'Hide Select'}}</button>
  <button class="control-button" (click)="toggleColumn('left')" >{{isLeftColumnHidden ? 'Show Left' : 'Hide Left'}}</button>
  <button class="control-button" (click)="toggleColumn('middle')">{{isMiddleColumnHidden ? 'Show Middle' : 'Hide Middle'}}</button>
  <button class="control-button" (click)="toggleColumn('right')">{{isRightColumnHidden ? 'Show Right' : 'Hide Right'}}</button>
</div>
```

```
.grid-container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 0;
  grid-row-gap: 0;
/* suggested chage */
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
}

.select-column, .left-column, .middle-column, .right-column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.select-column {
  /* suggested change */
  min-width: 150px;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.left-column {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.middle-column {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.right-column {
  grid-column: 4;
}

.hide-column {
  display: none;
}

.left-canvas, .middle-canvas, .right-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.controls-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.controls-container-left {
  left: 150px;
}

.control-button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('leftCanvas', {static: false}) leftCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  @ViewChild('middleCanvas', {static: false}) middleCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  @ViewChild('rightCanvas', {static: false}) rightCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  private leftCTX: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private middleCTX: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private rightCTX: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  isSelectColumnHidden: boolean = false;
  isLeftColumnHidden: boolean = false;
  isMiddleColumnHidden: boolean = false;
  isRightColumnHidden: boolean = false;


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.leftCTX = this.leftCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.leftCTX.fillStyle = 'blue';
    this.leftCTX.fillRect(0, 0, this.leftCanvas.nativeElement.width, this.leftCanvas.nativeElement.height);
    //this.leftCanvas.nativeElement.style.width = '100%'

    // @ts-ignore
    this.middleCTX = this.middleCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.middleCTX.fillStyle = 'red';
    this.middleCTX.fillRect(0, 0, this.middleCanvas.nativeElement.width, this.middleCanvas.nativeElement.height);

    // @ts-ignore
    this.rightCTX = this.rightCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.rightCTX.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    this.rightCTX.fillRect(0, 0, this.rightCanvas.nativeElement.width, this.rightCanvas.nativeElement.height);
}

toggleColumn(columnName: string): void {
  switch (columnName) {
    case 'select':
      this.isSelectColumnHidden = !this.isSelectColumnHidden;
      break;
    case 'left':
      this.isLeftColumnHidden = !this.isLeftColumnHidden;
      break;
    case 'middle':
      this.isMiddleColumnHidden = !this.isMiddleColumnHidden;
      break;
    case 'right':
      this.isRightColumnHidden = !this.isRightColumnHidden;
      break;
  }
}
  
}
```

Comment: Didn't read properly as usual..., Anyway `minmax(0, 150px)` is forcing the creation of a column with a minimum width of 150px. to fix it, change it to `auto` and `min-width:150px` on the element itself. Also it seems that you're using a single dimension, Flexbox is much of a perfect fit for this.

Comment: @Zohini I found this partly works. If I make the changes as suggest and close the red and blue columns, the yellow remains but with additional spacing to the left.

Comment: you seem to be running different code from the provided above? Because i don't see any space left anywhere. Also could you edit your question with a snippet illustrating the issue limited only to html, css *(js if needed)*

Comment: @Zohini I've updated as requested, highlighting the suggested changes in the CSS. Stackblitz example has also been updated

Comment: Yup, still not sure what space you're talking about, i don't see any

Comment: @Zohini in the StackBlitz link close the left or middle columns or both and see how the width of the white column expands. This is NOT what I desire.

Comment: ah, i only see space on Firefox nightly, on chrome it works fine, `minmax(0, auto)` fixed it for Firefox, Not exactly sure if it's a bug or what

Comment: @Zohini that's interesting .. it's the same reason why I used `minmax` for the canvas columns and I never thought to try that. It does work now as you say in Firefox and I never thought to try it in Chrome. Will investigate and raise a bug as required. Put as a reply and I will mark as accepted answer